# How do databases differ from MATLAB variables?

Tags: sql, database, matlab, sqlite

I'm used to working with data (sometimes large amounts of data) as matrices or cells in MATLAB. I'd like to make the switch to managing larger datasets through tools like SQLite.

So here is my question. How do I approach the conceptual switch from MATLAB variables (again multi-dimensional numerical matrices, as well as cells with text entries) to a database? For example, if I have a 4D matrix in MATLAB, is there a way to store that data directly as a table? Or would I have to do something like, say, make multiple labelled 2D tables? Is all data in a database stored in a table?

Is it right to think that the migration of data from MATLAB to a database would look like, more or less, a reorganization of the multidimensional MATLAB variables into a set of 2D tables?

Any experience with migrating data from a MATLAB environment to an sql-accessible database would be helpful.

Comment: Fun question, wrong Stack Exchange website I am afraid. This is better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: Oops! I just saw the "stats" in the url. I'll post it somewhere else. Thanks =)

Comment: Just flag it for moderator intervention, the rest will be taken care automatically. Do not cross-post, it is big no-no.

Comment: Okay great. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow;) So do you want to explicitly migrate from matlab to sqlite? Or is this just an option? A lot of us know matlab without knowing sql, so you might want to add some more specific tags for the database side. As far as matlab is concerned, a 4d matrix is a 4d matrix, period.

Comment: Thanks! My goal is to practice sql comands. I'd like to do that by transferring some MATLAB data to an sql-accessible database and playing around with it. I'm very comfortable working with vectors and matrices in MATLAB, but I'm curious how these variables (vectors, matrices, cells) can be reorganized into the 2D tables that seem to be the basic unit (?) of databases. Particularly I'm looking for people's experiences, best practices, etc.

Comment: OK, then I was right, you're primarily in need of an sql person, not a matlab person. But I can see you added those tags, so we'll see how it goes.

Comment: Ah yes, that's right. Thanks for suggesting the extra tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table is not a 2D array. The 4D 2*2*2*2 array is stored as {{{{1,2},{3,4}},{{5,6},{7,8}}},{{{9,10},{11,12}},{{13,14},{15,16}}}} ([it's even mentioned in the manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)). Which means in a database we can store it as 4 coordinates(x,y,z,t) and a value.

```
x|y|z|t|value
-+-+-+-+-----
1|1|1|1|1
1|1|1|2|2
1|1|2|1|3
.........
```

Now instead of doing A(1,2,3,4) you do `SELECT value FROM a WHERE x = 1 AND y = 2 AND z = 3 AND t = 4`

Though depending on what your data actually it may also be 3 coordinates and 2 values for each row

```
x|y|z|value1|value2
-+-+-+------+------
1|1|1|1     |2
1|1|2|3     |4
.........
```

Or if all you need is selecting the whole array at once you may store it as json or csv value all in one row.

If you have multiple array you will want an array_id column as well. The array_id may be a FK to a table holding name and description of the array. You probably should lookup the topic of array data structure and the database basics (you should look into [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) which databases are based on but there are differences).

Either way it's not really a Matlab vs. Databases question unless you have a specific question about some element of Matlab that is different from other languages.

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.